# Open comments on a certain Post

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

anyone know how can i open comments on a specific post in Wordpress? I tried `comments_open($id);` but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
   comments_open( get_the_ID() );
?>
```

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: 
i tried by specifieng it in functions.php, nothing changed.

```
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'feedbackOpen', 10, 2 );

function feedbackOpen( $open, $post_id ) {

    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if($post->post_type == 'product'){
        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Allow Comments', true)) {$open = true;}
    }else{
        return false;
    }

    return $open;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<?php comments_open( $post_id ); ?>` don't open comment on a specified post ID but either return true or false depending if comments are allowed or not for this post

There is how to open comment

```
$post = array(
   'ID'           => $post_id,
   'comment_status' => 'open'
);
wp_insert_post($post); // If given an ID will update the specified post
```

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/post.php

There is how to display the comment form for the current post

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

Comment: you think is possibile by using the built in functions to save a custom id of my user? Because i've users in my own table instead of wordpress one and ofc by default wordpress save every user comment not logged with user->id 0 and it's now what i want. Thanks

Comment: I would not advise you to change the defaut userId value of wordpress. But to add a meta_tags to your comment who will be for example 'myUserId'.Here is how to do so http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta

Answer (score 1):

Go to the administration. Find the particular post, and open it to go to its Edit page. Then, from the top right portion of the screen, click "Screen Options". From there, toggle "Discussion". This will make the "Discussion" meta box appear below your post's WYSIWYG editor. There you can tick "Allow Comments", and "Allow trackbacks and pingbacks on this page."

If you want to do this programatically, you can use the following code:

```
// Update post with ID 37
$my_post = array(
    'ID'           => 37,
    'comment_status' => 'open'
);

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: No i can't do this way. It must be automatic, every post with a specific post_type must have them enabled because i'm using comments system as a feedback system.

Comment: Make sure you have `"comments"` in the `"supports"` section of your `register_post_type()` call. I've also edited my answer above to contain an example solution for opening the comments programmatically.